# How to remove an object from an array that is in a separate object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

I have what I think is a pretty standard test/homework question that I can't quite finish.

It consists of creating a library, shelf, and book object. It requires populating the library with shelves and the shelves with books; it also needs to have a method to place a book on a shelf and remove a book from a shelf.

I have done most of it, but for two days I have been beating my head against a wall trying to remove a book from a shelf using an unshelf method.

Here is my code:

```
function Library() {
  this.shelves = [];

  //Logs all books in the library
  this.allBooks = function () {
    for (i = 0; i < library.shelves.length; i++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(library.shelves[i].books));
    }
  };


}

function Shelf(number) {
  this.number = number;
  this.books = [];

  //This method takes in the shelf number and logs the books on that shelf
  Library.prototype.booksOnShelf = function (shelfNum) {
    var x = shelfNum - 1;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(library.shelves[x].books));
  };
}

function Book(title) {
  this.title = title;

  //Adds a book to a specified shelf
  Library.prototype.enshelf = function (shelfNumber, bookTitle) {
    var y = shelfNumber - 1;
    library.shelves[y].books.push(new Book(bookTitle));
  };

  //this.unshelf = function (shelfNumber, bookTitle) {

  }

var library = new Library();

//Adds shelves to the library
library.shelves.push(new Shelf(1));
library.shelves.push(new Shelf(2));
library.shelves.push(new Shelf(3));

//Adds books to the library
library.shelves[0].books.push(new Book("A Storm of Swords"));
library.shelves[0].books.push(new Book("A Clash of Kings"));
library.shelves[0].books.push(new Book("A Game of Thrones"));
library.shelves[1].books.push(new Book("A Feast for Crows"));
library.shelves[2].books.push(new Book("A Dream of Dragons"));
library.shelves[2].books.push(new Book("Winds of Winter"));
library.shelves[2].books.push(new Book("A Dream of Spring"));




//library.allBooks(); //logs all the books in the library
//library.booksOnShelf(3); // logs all the books on a specified shelf
//console.log(library.shelves.length);//logs # of shelves in library
//library.enshelf(2, "Harry Potter");
//library.booksOnShelf(2);
library.allBooks();
//.unshelf("A Storm of Swords"); //Haven't figured this out yet
//library.allBooks();
```

So far everything works except for the unshelf method, and I have tried many different ways  to do it.

If someone could set me on the right path, I would appreciate it. Something I have been thinking about is putting the method in a different object. Also, I dont use any 'return's, which might be something that can help? When I try to call library.shelves[arg].books.splice(arg,arg), the console tells me I can't do it.

In summation, please help me take a specific book off a shelf.

Comment: You're mixing many concepts in the wrong way. I would suggest starting from scratch, reading some more about "Prototype inheritance". You have defined a prototype inside a constructor, forgot to declare `i`, you're using `library` as a global inside the `Library` constructor... Many things went wrong.

Comment: (OT) I've also found among your comments that you've tried to use a wrong property `//library.enshelf(2, "Harry Potter");` enshelf instead of `un`

Comment: TO retrieve a book, are you looking on how to retrieve a SPECIFIC book? Telling me that would help me construct a lovely loop

Comment: Roko, that is a method that puts a book on a shelf and it works. Brendan, I am looking to pull a specific book off a shelf and have it no longer there. elclanrs...that is kind of what I feared. I will probably start from scratch. Thank you all.